# Does Intellij IDEA completely support Android Archive (AAR)?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to use Android Archive (`aar`) library as a dependency in an android project. The project is mavenized and gets compiled/packaged completely and final output `apk` is working well. The project correctly gets opened in **Intellij IDEA 13.0.2** and the “`gen-external-apklibs`” folder is created. It sounds like everything (in the `aar` library such as custom UI elements and so on) is resolving correctly but when I try to build and run the project dozens of errors happen as follows

```
Android Dex: [***] Unable to execute DX
Android Dex: [***] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/***;
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
Android Dex: [***] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
Android Dex: [***] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Android Dex: [***] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Android Dex: [***] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Android Dex: [***] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Android Dex: [***] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
Android Dex: [***] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Android Dex: [***] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
```

The referenced `aar` library itself depends on another `aar` library

how may I resolve the issue?

**[UPDATED]**
The full error message included.

"`[***]`" is a substitute for my project name and "`com/***`" refers to a class belongs to inner **aar** library.